# Simple string hashing algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, c, strings, hash-map

I thought of a simple way to hash a string. By taking the ASCII decimal value of each character, multiplying it by 10, and adding all of the values computed together for each character in a string. Is there a name for this algorithm? I highly doubt I was the first one to think of this.

Compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 string.c -o string`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

size_t stringLength(const char* source)
{
    if(source == NULL) { return 0; }

    size_t length = 0;
    while(*source != '\0') {
        length++;
        source++;
    }
    return length;  
}

static size_t getHash(const char* source)
{
    size_t length = stringLength(source);
    size_t hash = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = source[i];
        int a = c - '0';
        hash = (hash * 10) + a;     
    } 

    return hash;
}

static const char *const testCases[] = {
    "this",
    "is",
    "a",
    "test",
    "but",
    "i",
    "should",
    "use",
    "real",
    "dictonary"
};

#define TABLE_SIZE (16)

int main()
{
    size_t name = getHash("Ryan McCullagh");
    printf("%zu\n", name);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(testCases) / sizeof(testCases[0])); i++) {
        const char* source = testCases[i];  
        size_t hash = getHash(source);
        printf("%s <==> %zu\n", source, (hash % TABLE_SIZE));

    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For an idea *why* it is a bad idea to use an even multiplier, append a constant string to each key.

Comment: The description suggests that you are converting each character to ASCII, but I don't see that in the code.  But there's no need for such conversion if your hashes are only ever local - just use the native character coding (which is what the code here does).

Answer (score 7):

1. Don't check for NULL pointer argument. The function should expect a valid null-terminated string, it's responsibility of the caller to ensure correct argument.
2. You don't need to know the string length. Check for null-terminator right in the hash loop.
3. It's possible to write it shorter and cleaner.

   ```
   static size_t getHash(const char* cp)
   {
       size_t hash = 0;
       while (*cp)
           hash = (hash * 10) + *cp++ - '0';
       return hash;
   }
   ```
4. It's not quite clear what do you mean by "ASCII decimal value". Are you referring to this expression in your code: `c - '0'`? Well, suppose at some moment `c == 'Z'`, so this expression amounts to `'Z' - '0'`. If we substitute ASCII codes for these characters, then we get `90 - 48`, this is equal to 42 which is ASCII code for `'*'` character. So you have transformed `'Z'` into `'*'`. Is this somehow supposed to improve the quality of your hash function? I'm in doubt.
5. Are you aware that for the same expression `c - '0'` for a number of possible `c` values (e.g. `' '`, `'!'`, and anything with ASCII value less than 48) you will get a negative result and when you add it to the `hash` it will be sign-extended and converted to a huge unsigned value, something like `0xffffffffffffffxx`?
6. If you are looking for a short and simple hash function then perhaps either of these might work for you.

   ```
   /* D. J. Bernstein hash function */
   static size_t djb_hash(const char* cp)
   {
       size_t hash = 5381;
       while (*cp)
           hash = 33 * hash ^ (unsigned char) *cp++;
       return hash;
   }

   /* Fowler/Noll/Vo (FNV) hash function, variant 1a */
   static size_t fnv1a_hash(const char* cp)
   {
       size_t hash = 0x811c9dc5;
       while (*cp) {
           hash ^= (unsigned char) *cp++;
           hash *= 0x01000193;
       }
       return hash;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I have only a few comments about your code, otherwise, it looks good. The string hashing algo you've devised should have an alright distribution and it is cheap to compute, though the constant `10` is probably not ideal (check the link at the end).

1. I don't see a need for reinventing the wheel here. You should use [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to compute the length of strings. It will more than likely be a lot better optimized than your custom `stringLength()`.
2. However, you don't need to compute the string's length beforehand. `getHash()` can be optimized by using the null terminator in the string itself to infer its length. No need to do a pre-pass just to compute the length:

   ```
   static size_t getHash(const char* source)
   {    
       if (source == NULL) {
           return 0;
       }

       size_t hash = 0;
       while (*source != '\0') {
           char c = *source++;
           int a = c - '0';
           hash = (hash * 10) + a;     
       } 
       return hash;
   }
   ```
3. Two minor details: In C, you should add `void` to the parameter list of functions that take no arguments, so `main` should be `int main(void)`. Also, you don't need to explicitly `return 0` at the end of `main`. This function is treated specially by the compiler. If there's no explicit return, a `return 0` is added at the end of `main` by default.

---

If you are interested in knowing more about hash functions and algorithms, I recommend reading [this article](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx).

Comment: #3 is not correct. It is okay to have `int main()` definition. A definition like `int func(void)` is only needed to let the compiler check that you always call `func` without extra arguments. But normally you do not call `main()` yourself, there is no need for compiler to check non-existing calls, and so this extra typing is of no use. Also compiler doesn't treat `main` specially. It is treated specially by the C run-time library (libcrt). By the way, libcrt always calls `main` with `argc` and `argv` arguments. So in fact it is more correct to define your `main` function as `main()`.

Comment: @AlekseyDemakov Yes, you are correct about `void`. I wasn't detailed enough on that point because it is a minor detail. Though since it is a good practice to add `void` to allow better compile-time checking, I don't see harm in being consistent and adding it to `main` as well. The compiler does treat `main` differently when it comes to omitting the return statement. In C99, reaching the end of the function will return 0. That is not true for any other function but `main`.

Comment: Also, we shouldn't assume that the runtime will always call `main` with `argc` and `argv`. That's only true for Windows, AFAIK.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected on the main return value. Your were right about it for -std=c99 and -std=c11 modes.